# Inverting text color depending on video background

Tags: html, css, colors, background

I'm looking for a way to invert the color of text depending on the video color I have in background.
I din't find any way to make it without constant color value which is necessary because the color behind the text is never the same.

I already tried things using `mix-blend-mode` and changing the text color but of course in vain :

```css
.my-text {
    color: black;
    mix-blend-mode: difference
}
```

This just get me the text in black.

I also tried `filter: invert(1);` but it just got me the text in black as it doesn't take count of the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try replacing `color: black` with `color: white`](https://codepen.io/jakoblindskog/pen/VwjGaYG): [image: From codepen]

Big credit to [the original codepen](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/kkYawX).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's working on Firefox, but not on Chrome. The color is just white on Chrome and the invert effect isn't done

Comment: I finally figured out it wasn't working because of the z-index. I just deleted the z-index  value on my text and background so that they are effectively one on top of the other.